# Как сделать ембед для дс бота?

Tags: python, discord, бот

Вот у меня есть код для просмотра аватара пользователя, и я хочу сделать чтобы аватар был в ембеде

```py
@bot.command()
async def avatar(ctx, member:discord.Member):
await ctx.send(member.avatar_url)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно отправить аватар в ембеде через **description**, а можно и создать отдельное поле. Если это понадобится - напишите в комментарии.

Вот отправка ембеда(аватар в **description**.):

```py
@bot.command()
async def avatar(ctx, member:discord.Member):
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(title='Автар пользователя ', description=member.avatar_url, color=0x00ff00)))
```

Comment: Мой ответ помог?

Comment: Круто) Спасибо, сам думал, как отправить)

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия-3-8 не за что)